# AppWidget trouble on Boot (application gets restarted in the middle of initialization)

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I've got a stockmarket tracking Android application, and it comes with an AppWidget to display prices. Normally it works fine, although it seems to be having some trouble on the first load after booting.

The load sequence is supposed to work like this:

1. Phone boots
2. AppWidget `onUpdate` called.
3. AppWidget needs data from internet, starts a service which pulls quotes from the internet:

   ```
   Log.d("PortfolioMap", "Widget is requesting a MANUAL_UPDATE");
   Intent newIntent = new Intent(context.getPackageName() + ".MANUAL_UPDATE");
   context.startService(newIntent);
   ```
4. On internet update completion, cache result in custom `Application` class, fire `sendBroadcast` to AppWidget receiver to refresh the data.

   ```
   Log.d("PortfolioMap", "Updating portfolio with results for " + updateData.size() + " stocks with value " + dbgValue);
   Intent newIntent = new Intent(getPackageName() + ".DATA_UPDATE_COMPLETE");
   this.sendBroadcast(newIntent);
   ```
5. AppWidget receives broadcast, calls onUpdate to draw with the new data.

   ```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       super.onReceive(context, intent);
       Log.d("PortfolioMap", "Widget received broadcast " + intent.getAction());
       ...
       this.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, ids);
   }
   ```

What happens in reality is that between step 4 (DATA_UPDATE_COMPLETE broadcast sent), and step 5 (DATA_UPDATE_COMPLETE broadcast received), there is a roughly 10 second delay in which my application is restarted (`onCreate` of `Application` class is called a second time after step 4).

After the application is restarted with a new PID, it still receives the broadcast that was sent by the first instance of the application, but at this point the Application data has been wiped out.

Does anyone have an idea why my application would be getting reset in the middle of loading, and why the broadcast is received even after the application is reset? This seems very strange to me. The restart always seems to come immediately after the Motorola broadcast `ACTION_WIDGET_ADDED`, but I'm not sure if that's relevant or what that means.

Here's my log. Note how the PID changes in the last three lines, and it says the "application is being created" for a second time.

```
 21:37:55.347: D/PortfolioMap(4299): Application is being created
 21:37:55.467: D/PortfolioMap(4299): Widget received broadcast android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED
 21:37:55.477: D/PortfolioMap(4299): Widget onUpdate called
 21:37:55.477: D/PortfolioMap(4299): Widget is requesting a MANUAL_UPDATE
 21:37:55.497: D/PortfolioMap(4299): InternetUpdater received broadcast MANUAL_UPDATE
 21:37:55.927: D/PortfolioMap(4299): Updating portfolio with results for 3 stocks with value 8973.326
 21:38:05.337: D/PortfolioMap(4299): Widget received broadcast com.motorola.blur.home.ACTION_WIDGET_ADDED
 21:38:18.417: D/PortfolioMap(4778): Application is being created
 21:38:18.497: D/PortfolioMap(4778): Widget received broadcast com.karwosts.PortfolioMap.DATA_UPDATE_COMPLETE
 21:38:18.497: D/PortfolioMap(4778): Starting widget redraw with portfolio 'All Portfolios' (value:0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had some experience of this dealing with a major device manufacturer and observed this myself. It was commented that on a system boot the OS doesn't have sufficient allocated memory and is forced to kill any active processes, reallocating them as and when it completes initialising the OS. This might well explain your observations.